# Foreign key migration using django south

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-south

I changed the reference of a foreign key with out change the name of the field, now I have 2 constraints on the same field point to different tables.
My model was like this

```
class Activity(models.Model):
    ...
    source = models.ForeignKey(FSObject)
```

and became

```
class Activity(models.Model):
    ...
    source = models.ForeignKey(FreezedRef)
```

And now I getting this message when running my tests:

```
IntegrityError: (1452, 'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`test_tcf_api`.`storage_activity`, CONSTRAINT `source_id_refs_id_fc96b4b044ceb88` FOREIGN KEY (`source_id`) REFERENCES `storage_fsobject` (`id`))')
```

How should I delete this old reference, apparently, South skipped it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you update anything else in the same migration? Did they work or break? I only ask because I've never had South break anything when running a migration - it will usually raise an exception during that process if something is wrong.

Comment: He's most likely dealing with an idiosyncrasy in mysql.  I've run into this before where one table was myISAM and another was InnoDB.  South/django created the contraint which of course fails since myISAM doesn't support foreign keys.  Not sure exactly how to end up on that path, but I've seen the exact problem before.

Comment: Hence my first suggestion to drop the garbage database and move to something that doesn't suck so much.  This is just one of a multitude of issues with using mysql

Answer (score -1):

1. Stop using bad databases like MySQL that create innane problems like this due to only being a kinda sorta database (sorry couldn't resist, but it's true)
2. `ALTER TABLE tbl_name DROP FOREIGN KEY fk_symbol;` Straight from the mysql docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

Comment: Why do you think MySQL is bad?

Comment: It's not remotely ACID compliant by default in ways that really blow, No ForeignKey constraints, no transactions, Unable to index fields over 1k (you can argue this would be bad design anyway, but still that's only 300ish unicode characters), unable to index function results, no implementation of EXPLAIN ANALYZE, no transactions during schema altering commands, queries only use one index per query per table (forcing the use of a ton of multicolumn indexes instead of combining indexes on the fly).  I'm sure I could think of more if I spent some time, basically I find something new every week

Comment: Obviously I realize that a couple (no fk's and no transactions) of these could be helped with innodb, most couldn't but some could.  InnoDB should be the default if you want to play fast and loose to gain a little performance you should swap to MyISAM, not the other way around.  The only thing really good about MySQL IMO is that it was the first widely adopted open source DB and opened a lot of options to the web.  Something similar can be said about PHP and I don't think many people would argue that PHP is amazing or the best tool.